# Mongo DB C# API, Converts GUID to LUUID instead of UUID

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, uuid, guid

I have a C# MongoDB driver 2.15.0, which inserts data to MongoDB using Modals. But in my Test Environment the data inserted in MongoDB is **UUID**. But in Production its inserted as **LUUID**, I need it as UUID in production as well, what could be the reason?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing. It seems the default `GuidRepresentation` for the MongoDB driver is `CSharpLegacy`. Pulling UUIDs from a Mongo source will appear fine in the C# application, but inserting data back into Mongo will result in LUUIDs (legacy UUIDs).

As far as I'm aware, you can't "fix" this problem in your screenshot, since that's not the root of the behaviour. I had to set the following in `BsonDefaults` **before** instantiating a MongoClient to connect:

```
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;
```

Once the connection is created, the `GuidRepresentation` is set and can't be changed in any way I was able to find.

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.22/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_GuidRepresentation.htm